# TemplateBinding for Dynamic Controls

Tags: binding

I create a templated RadioButton at run time. After initializing the templated RadioButton, I set the DataContext and Tag property and then add this button in a StackPanel. The problem is that the template binding does not work. below is the XAML and the code behind. All this work if I assign values to these properties in XAML. Any ideas?

Code:
TemplatedRadioButton commandButton = new TemplatedRadioButton();
commandButton.DataContext = "bla"; // Some txt that I will.
commandButton.Tag = MyImage; // This is the ImageIcon that I create at run time too.
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(commandButton);

XAML:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry:
Code:
TemplatedRadioButton commandButton = new TemplatedRadioButton();
commandButton.DataContext = "bla"; // Some txt that I will.
commandButton.Tag = MyImage; // This is the ImageIcon that I create at run time too.
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(commandButton);

XAML:

```
 <Grid Margin="0 8 0 1">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
   <RowDefinition Name="textheight" Height="2*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Tag" Margin=" 4 4 6 6"   HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>

  <TextBlock Name="caption" Text="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" FontSize="11" FontFamily="/Fonts/#Lucida Grande" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FF313131" Margin="0 2 0 6"/>
 </Grid>
</Border>
```